# Periodically execution of backend script

Tags: javascript, apache

My requirement is to execute a back-end script as long as the user has the browser page open and kill the back-end script for user's session in case of any issues at browser side - like user clicks close browser page / browser crash etc and others that we can think off or might be possible.

My requirement is to start a back-end script on user demand and updating the user page with details. At the same time we need to stop the script when user's exists due to any cause. I do understand that having buttons on page to start / stop would help - but what if user closes the page - my back-end script would keep running infinitely.

Please advice which way I can implement  the same.

Comment: I don't know what your goal is, but I'd bet good money that is _not_ the best way to achieve it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: How is the server supposed to know the page has closed? You'd need to handle disconnects as page close.

Comment: several ways, including ajax pulls, websockets, close events

Comment: @Alex - My result web page is a report page which would be activated based upon users request; I would then keep on adding details in the users page via the back-end application logs. As such it would be a basically a tail of data that is getting added to the back-end application logs

Comment: One addition is that I already have a web app setup - so this is an enhancing functionality of the web tool - the current setup is via Apache which is listening @ port 80 and calls a CGI scripts to service the request - hence as such will websockets / sockets work - cause then I understand that I need to have one more app listening at a different port? The request would come as a part of the main web tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily implemented with long polling technology. You can use:

```
setInterval(function(){
    /*some code to execute ajax request to backend*/
}, timeIntervalInMS);
```

Or better search google for long polling plugins in javascript and you are good to go.

By this technique browser will issue a request every timeInterval in miliseconds to the backend as long as user has it's browser open.

Comment: Well actually then on the first request I would start capturing / rendering application logs to user's UI page. Now I need to keep doing this until user discards the page - the reason why I am asking  for a foolproof mechanism is to avoid chances of the back-end script running indefinitely even though there are no users to whom data has to be rendered.

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem, as I told it will execute as long as client has page open. You just have to sort out user sessions on backend.

Comment: @Butkus - Thanks for your post. We have back-end servers that generates logs and which I need to render to a UI user web page in his / her browser. So when the user initiates for it, I would start an infinite loop to capture / render all added application logs by the servers (something like data that keeps added to logs). The issue is that how would my back-end server know when to stop executing the script  - a foolproof method to escape from being running indefinitely with no objective, like an orphaned child process.

Comment: Why not do it like ping/pong style? You client pings a server and server updates time remaining until it stops execution and when client closes browser it stops pinging server and server's timeout runs out - server stops executing script.

Comment: The issue with this approach would be that until next ping comes I need to know where last I processed my application logs and pick up from there while the application logs would still being populated. Like I processed 100 lines and respond back to UI now there are 500 lines so I need to process from 101 line to 500th or till a point and then keep retaining the last processed line. So I would rather keep processing my app logs and render it directly to UI page but just have to know when to stop and stop gracefully such that no orphans are there

Comment: Well I really doubt that you can do anything else about that. This would be the same technique what IRC clients used, they ping client and clients pongs back if you don't pong back server will drop your connection as if you were timeouted.
Now if you don't want to process data into the future simply processes it only when client pings you.